# Any way to adjust Bluetooth radio sensitivity?

Tags: macos, bluetooth

I've got a Bluetooth keyboard and mouse connected to a MacBook at my desk in my home office. When I'm laptopping outside the office (which is honestly most of the time), away from the keyboard/mouse, they stay connected, thereby chewing through batteries and popping up warnings.

I was hoping there was a way to adjust the radio sensitivity or cutoff or something. For example, I'm outside the office right now and they're about -75 dB RSSi, and I'd like to tell the system "don't connect to devices with signal below -60 dB".

Comment: A simpler solution would be to turn off the BT devices or put them in a faraday cage.

Comment: @IconDaemon yeah, turning them off is the most explicit way to deal with it, but I forget, and this seems like a problem automation could deal with. As for a Faraday cage, sure, my wife would love that :P

Comment: The faraday cage can be a simple as a mylar [anti-static bag](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01AAYYNPI/).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up [solving it myself](https://github.com/nfirvine/macos-low-bluetooth/blob/master/low_bluetooth_threshold.sh). In short:

1. get signal strength from `system_profiler`; if bad, turn off bluetooth
2. check AC power with `pmset`; turn on Bluetooth if connected

Needs `blueutil` to toggle Bluetooth.

I couldn't find a way to tell a device to shut off remotely.